# WriteableBitmap.render is not working in windows 8.1 c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, writeablebitmap, writeablebitmapex

is there a way to add WriteableBitmapExwinphone.dll to my project ?

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Runtime apps use [RenderTargetBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.aspx) instead of WriteableBitmap.Render. WriteableBitmap.Render is Silverlight only.